# Solving this system of equations without a CAS: $4=a+c$, $5=d+ac+b$, $4=ad+bc$, $4=bd$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, fractions

Solving this system of equations : 
$$4=a+c$$ $$5=d+ac+b$$ $$4=ad+bc$$ $$4=bd$$

Anyone knows how to solve this without a CAS?

Comment: What are $a,b,c,d$? Are they integers, real numbers?

Comment: What is it $c5$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg looks like space between the equations

Comment: What have you tried (without a CAS)? Have you found a solution with a CAS? Please edit the question to clarify. Put the equations on separate lines. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: this are four equations with space between them @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Yes, we can all solve the system without CAS, but we don't do homework for lazy students.

Comment: I actually don't know a method to solve this without CAS, give me a method and I'll try it @B.Goddard

Comment: First expend the tiny bit of effort it takes to learn how to post on this site.  Why would we go to the trouble of helping you when you won't lift a finger yourself.  You didn't bother to read the intro.  You didn't learn anything about MathJax.  You didn't show any work or give any context for your problem.  Pah!

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad syntax, I edited it by using MathJax. @B.Goddard

Answer (score 2):

We obtain $$c=4-a$$ and $$d=\frac{4}{b},$$ which gives
$$\frac{4}{b}+b+a(4-a)=5$$ and
$$a\cdot\frac{4}{b}+b(4-a)=4.$$
From the last equation we obtain:
$$a=\frac{4b^2-4b}{b^2-4},$$ which gives
$$\frac{4}{b}+b+\frac{4b^2-4b}{b^2-4}\left(4-\frac{4b^2-4b}{b^2-4}\right)=5$$ or
$$\frac{b^2-5b+4}{b}+\frac{16b(b-4)(b-1)}{(b^2-4)^2}=0$$ or
$$(b-1)(b-4)\left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{16b}{(b^2-4)^2}\right)=0$$ or
$$(b-1)(b-4)=0$$ because $$(b^2-4)^2+16b^2>0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: thank you, really helps me and yes, I can end it from this point

Answer (score 0):

A particular solution is $(a,b,c,d)=(4,4,0,1)$. This becomes from the following:
$$\begin{cases}a+c=4\\ac+b+d=5\\ad+bc=4\\bd=4\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}c(4-c)+b+d=5\\d(4-c)+bc=4\\bd=4\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}4c-c^2+\dfrac 4d+d=5\\4d-cd+\frac{4c}{d}=4\end{cases}$$ The third system with two unknowns give as resultant $$d^6-5d^5+12d^4-40d^3+48d^2-80d+64=(d-1)(d-4)(d^2+4)^2=0$$ which gives the solution above and others whose calculation is  left for the OP.