# How do you solve the following nonlinear equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How to solve the following system of equations

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> a+c=12\\
> b+ac+d=86\\
> bc+ad=300\\
> bd=625\\
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help and a lot fewer down votes if you provide some context for your questions.  What have yo done so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: What are [the chances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664582/solving-this-system-of-equations-without-a-cas-4-ac-5-dacb-4-adbc)...

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, there will be two sets of solutions. If they may be complex, there will be probably six.

Answer (score 4):

This system of equations corresponds to a factorization of $$f(x)=x^4+12x^3+86x^2+300x+625$$ into two quadratics as 
$$f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
The roots of $f(x)$ are $-3-4i$ and $-3+4i$, each having multiplicity $2$. So what should the quadratic factors of $f(x)$ look like?

Comment: Thanks for reply these equations are obtained by comparison. I have calculated by matlab. But need to know how to solve these set of equations. By Substitution it gives 4 order equation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $b=\cfrac {625}{d}$ from your last equation, and $a=-c+12$ from your first equation.

Substitute $b$ and $a$ into your second equation to get $\cfrac{625}{d}+(-c+12)(c)+d=86$

Do the same for your third equation.

Comment: You want $b,$ not $d$ in the denominator of the fraction.

Comment: From that onwards it become nightmare thanks for reply

Comment: Can we solve them analytically or have to opt for numerical methods